# How to filter all multiples of a certain number out of a list in Haskell using filter

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I know I can make a function to do this but can I use the filter function from the prelude. I can easily filter all numbers larger than 3 for instance from a list using

```
filter (>3) [list]
```

But I want something like

```
filter (not (.. `mod` 4 == 0)) [list]
```

that filters out all multiples of four. I put the .. here because I dont know what goes there. Is there any way I can do this using the filter function or should I make my own function to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `(>3)` is really `\x -> x>3`. You can devise any condition after `\x ->`, for example `\x -> mod x 4 /= 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
filter (\n -> not (n `mod` 4 == 0)) [list]
```

The `\n` is read "lambda n", and introduces an anonymous function. Namely, the function which, given `n` tests if it is not a multiple of `4`.

Otherwise, you can use the "pointfree" style, in which you compose several functions:

```
filter (not . (== 0) . (`mod` 4)) [list]
```

The function reads as: take the input, reduce it modulo `4`, then test if the result is equal to 0, and finally negate the result of such test.

Note that you can also use `/= 0` instead of `== 0` and negation.

Answer (score 3):

As an aside: the latest versions of ghc have an extension called [`TypeHoles`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Typed_holes), that can sometimes help with those "I put the .. here because I dont know what goes there" types of situations.

It is enabled by default in ghci. If you leave `_` in place on an expression in your code, ghc will try to infer what type a thing in the `_` could have.

```
# :t filter _ [1,2,3,4]::[Int]

<interactive>:1:8:
    Found hole `_' with type: Int -> Bool
    In the first argument of `filter', namely `_'
    In the expression: filter _ [1, 2, 3, ....] :: [Int]
```

It becomes more helpful as the types become more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda expression:

```
filter (\x -> x `mod` 4 /= 0) list
```

Or if you're adventurous use point free style:

```
filter ((/= 0) . (`mod` 4)) list
```

(I assume the `[]` around `list` was a mistake, you probably don't want a list of just one element called `list`.)